# Standard Errors from logistic regression in keras significance test

Tags: python, keras, logistic-regression

I have two independent variables (x1,x2), which I use to predict y (binary). With a logistic regression, I could just use the standard errors of each estimated coefficient to test them for significance.

*However*, I have a deep network that builds on inputA (some text) and inputB (numerical data).

This means, I would have to extract the standard errors from the last layer, to test the coefficient of inputB for significance. Otherwise, it would not be possible to check if inputB actually adds significantly to the model. **How do I extract the standard errors from a logistic regression run in an deep learning model (keras)?**

```
#### Network
# define two sets of inputs
inputA = Input(shape=(32,))
inputB = Input(shape=(128,))

# the first branch operates on the first input
x = Dense(8, activation="relu")(inputA)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
x = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)

# the second branch opreates on the second input
y = Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputB)
y = Dense(32, activation="relu")(y)
y = Dense(4, activation="relu")(y)
y = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)

# combine the output of the two branches
combined = concatenate([x.output, y.output])

# our model will accept the inputs of the two branches and
# then output a single value
preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output')(combined) 
model = Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=[preds])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit([x_train,numeric], y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=50)
```

**Edit:**

Now, I found this useful link:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89484/how-to-compute-the-standard-errors-of-a-logistic-regressions-coefficients

So I assume I could use `y_pred =  model.predict(inputs=[x_train,numeric], verbose=1)  # gives probabilities`

and then, I have to input `combined` into the following code... but how do I do that.. or is my approach erroneous?

```
#### Standard Error testing
# Design matrix -- add column of 1's at the beginning of your X_train matrix
X_design = np.hstack([np.ones((combined.shape[0], 1)), combined])

# Initiate matrix of 0's, fill diagonal with each predicted observation's variance
V = np.diagflat(np.product(y_preds, axis=1))


# Covariance matrix
covLogit = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.dot(X_design.T, V), X_design))
```

Can someone please add some suggestions / verification?

**Edit2**

The thing that confuses me is that I have two inputs, a numeric-input `numeric` and a non-numeric input `x_train`. To test the coefficients, I have to create a matrix in the shape of the *combined-input* (that's actually filled with the combined input).

Then I can use the models prediction, to test the last layers coefficients for significance (as described by the reference link for coefficient testing).

But how do I input the compined-input.. or am I somewhere mistaken?

Comment: How do you define `predProbs`? What is the error message? At first glance, it looks good to me

Comment: Oh, ```predProbs``` are the ```y_preds``` - my mistake

Comment: Alright. In this case, according to the answer on StackExchange, `V` should be defined as: `V = np.diagflat(y_preds * (1 - y_preds))`, shouldn't it? From my point of view, after applying this modification, this should yield the behavior of the StackExchange answer

Comment: Have you seen [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) values?  
Something like that or [permutation tests](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/permutation-importance) look like they could be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this answer is good for you....

#### What would I do?

- Test a network with only `inputA`.
- Test a network with only `inputB`.
- Test the combined network.

Ther winner is the one I'll use.

---

#### Getting how much of each input the network is letting through:

If you get the weights of the last layer, you will have two tensors:

- A `(1, 8)` weights matrix (or `(8, 1)`, doesn't matter much in this case).
- A `(1,)` bias value

Get them:

```
w, b = model.get_layer("output").get_weights()
```

Flatten `w` (it doesn't matter because you have only 1 output unit) and see how much the network is weighting each of the inputs. Following the order in which you concatenated x and y:

```
w = w.reshape((-1,))
weights_x = w[:4] #the first 4 weigths are multiplying `x.output`   
weights_y = w[4:] #the last 4 weights are multiplying `y.output`
```

Comment: Considering one model with just inputA, and another model with inputA and inputB is a good suggestion. I already consider that by comparing the F-scores of the models. However, a coefficient significance test - just for the logistic regression in the layer - should also lead to interesting conclusions.. but, Iam not sure, how to retrieve the ```combined-input``` and conduct the significance test